# NO EFI Partition system found during Ubuntu installation with Windows in dual boot mode

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I have Windows 10 installed on my system and I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04.2 along with windows 10 in dual boot mode. I have a single HDD, and since my C: didn't had as much space as 20GB, hence I had allocated space for Ubuntu by partitioning from E: (E: is also a primary partition in my system). I am installing using USB flash drive
During installation of Ubuntu, it didn't detect windows and I went ahead with something else option, and I selected my partition, and also specified the mount point as /, with use as option ext4. However in next step I'm getting an error saying [No EFI System partition was found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIka5.jpg) 
My Windows always runs using Bios, and not using Uefi. If windows is not using Uefi i do not know why i am getting this error. Please provide some help regarding this error, it's causes and tentative solutions. Thanks

Comment: You have new UEFI hardware but installed Windows in the old BIOS/MBR configuration. You either have to reinstall Windows in UEFI mode, or boot Ubuntu live installer in BIOS boot mode to install in BIOS boot mode. Both Windows & Ubuntu install in boot mode that you boot installer, UEFI or BIOS. Microsoft has required vendors to install Windows in UEFI boot mode to gpt drives since Windows 8 released in 2012, but users have the option for BIOS, but more for large companies with older BIOS systems.

Comment: Yes made the Ubuntu to boot in bios mode, by changing it in boot manager during startup, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue it was because my windows was running in bios and I was trying to install Ubuntu in uefi. In your Ubuntu live USB check for EFI folder and delete it, then try to install. It worked for me hope it works for you.